# Magento - Set Custom Attribute not working in customer_register_success Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer-attribute, attribute-set

I am using the extension 'Customer Attributes'. I can modify values in the Magento backend in e.g. a controller. And I can read the values programmatically via PHP, but I can not set the values in my **customer_register_success** Observer.

```
public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$customer = $event->getCustomer();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
$customid = $customer->getData('customid');
$customer->setData(array("customid"=>24)) ;
```

This last row is not working. And I can not save().

*On my stage environment* after printing out the value before and after (echo $customer->getData("customid")) it showed the change. But I could not save().

*On my live environment* it crashed while registration process, saying ,, Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails "

Comment: You always need to save models to get the data in the database

Comment: I am trying to setData and save in a observer of customer_register_success.  But it a) does not save [highlighting in the registration frontend that an email is required] or b) crashes e.g. saying Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.